# ArrayIndexOutOfBoudsException

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

so I've been trying to compile this program with a "render" method, which accesses pixels from a sprite sheet, but keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, with the exception on the line with pixels[(x + xPos) and so on

```
public void render(int xPos, int yPos, int tile, int colour){
    xPos -= xOffset;
    yPos -= yOffset;

    int xTile = tile%32;
    int yTile = tile/32;
    int tileOffset = (xTile<<3) + (yTile<<3)*sheet.width;
    for(int y = 0; y<8; y++){
        if(y + yPos<0 || y + yPos>= height) continue;
        int ySheet = y;
        for(int x = 0; x<8; x++){
            if(x + xPos<0 || x + xPos>= width) continue;
            int xSheet = x;
            int col = (colour >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet* sheet.width + tileOffset]*8)) & 255;
            if(col < 255) {
                pixels[(x + xPos) + (y + yPos) * width] = col;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, is this a problem with my computer, or with the programming?

EDIT: found the problem, it was in another method that declared pixels[] where I accidentally put this.width = width and *this.height = width*. Let this be a warning to any other developers!

Comment: Please give the full stack trace.  Please also give us the declaration of `pixels`.

Comment: Remember: 99.99% of the times there's nothing wrong with the computer.

Comment: it seems you are trying to access an index that extends beyond the pixels[] array